# Testing a Symfony 3.4+ bundle with a database connection

Tags: database, testing, bundle, symfony-3.4

I'm trying to determine the best way to configure a bundle for testing using Travis that makes a connection to a database. Normally when the bundle is used inside a project the DB connection is specified as part of the project configuration (config/packages/doctrine.yaml). However, when using CI tests the bundle gets installed in the test project root and the dependencies in /vendor. I need to configure the connection within the bundle purely for testing purposes.

What I would like to do is configure a doctrine connection using a SQLite memory database, create the schema as part of the CI test, and run my phpunit tests. All the tests run fine if the bundle is installed in a normal Symfony project.

I'm getting totally frustrated trying to configure the database. I've been at this for a couple of days now trying to trace what is (not) going on when loading the configs.

I have a kernel which I load in my test class that extends KernelTestCase as follows:

```
class CommandSchedulerTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private $entityManager;

    protected static function getKernelClass()
    {
        return TestKernel::class;
    }

    protected function setUp()
    {
        self::bootKernel();

        $this->entityManager = static::$kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
    }
...
```

And my kernel class:

```
<?php

namespace Xact\CommandScheduler\Tests;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Kernel\MicroKernelTrait;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollectionBuilder;

class TestKernel extends Kernel
{
    use MicroKernelTrait;

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = [
            \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle::class,
            \Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle::class,
            \Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineCacheBundle\DoctrineCacheBundle::class,
            \Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle::class,
        ];

        foreach ($bundles as $class) {
            yield new $class();
        }
    }

    protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollectionBuilder $routes)
    {
        $confDir = $this->getProjectDir().'/Resources/config';
        $routes->import($confDir.'/routing.yaml');
    }

    protected function configureContainer(ContainerBuilder $c, LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $confDir = $this->getProjectDir().'/Resources/config';
        $loader->load($confDir . '/test/doctrine.yaml');
        $loader->load($confDir . '/test/framework.yaml');
    }
}
```

And for reference, my doctrine.yaml file:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: "sqlite:///:memory:"
```

I managed to hack the configuration loading process and I can see the contents of my framework.yaml file are being added to the parameters list. I also know the doctrine.yaml file is being parsed because if I add anything other than 'dbal' or 'orm' under the root I get an error. However, I don't seem to get the connection in the list of parameters.

I'm getting errors like this:

```
1) Xact\CommandScheduler\Tests\CommandSchedulerTest::testSet
InvalidArgumentException: Doctrine ORM Manager named "" does not exist.

/var/projects/command-scheduler/vendor/doctrine/persistence/lib/Doctrine/Persistence/AbstractManagerRegistry.php:151
/var/projects/command-scheduler/Tests/CommandSchedulerTest.php:25
```

This makes me think that my doctrine config is not being correctly loaded.

I have also tried adding the config via PrependExtensionInterface::prepend as I've read suggestions that loading DB connections during the Kernel::configureContainer is too late. However, this achieved nothing and presented other errors indicating that any config files loaded in the kernel are ignored.

I would deeply appreciate some help in determining if I am on the right track with this, am I trying to do something that can't be done? Have I missed something very basic in my setup? I don't know. What I do know is that I have lost a little more hair which is disturbing!

Answer (score 0):

Well after a bit more head scratching I finally found my error. If you don't specify an 'orm' section in the doctrine.yaml file the ORM configuration is never loaded via the doctrine-bundle DoctrineExtension class (see load() and ormLoad()).

Having updated my yaml file to the following I've got it working. I also added the driver parameter as this defaults to 'pdo_mysql', it may get fixed internally but it just looked wrong when I was debugging the connection parameters list.

Resources/test/doctrine.yaml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: "sqlite:///:memory:"
        driver: 'pdo_sqlite'

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            XactCommandSchedulerBundle:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/Entity'
                prefix: 'Xact\CommandScheduler\Entity'
```

I also had to add dotrine/orm to my composer.json file. In my full Symfony app that was being pulled in by the symfony/orm-pack metapackage.

```
...
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.12",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.5",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~5.4",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~3.5",
        "symfony/yaml": "^3.4.30",
    },
...
```

To complete the picture in case someone else wants to do this, here are the other files in my setup.

Resources/config/test/framework.yaml

```
framework:
    secret: '78yb%$5JuI)7R'
    test: true
    session:
        storage_id: session.storage.mock_file
```

DependencyInjection/XactCommandSchedulerExtension.php

```
namespace Xact\CommandScheduler\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;

class XactCommandSchedulerExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yaml');
    }
}
```

Tests/TestKernel.php

```
<?php

namespace Xact\CommandScheduler\Tests;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Kernel\MicroKernelTrait;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollectionBuilder;

class TestKernel extends Kernel
{
    use MicroKernelTrait;

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = [
            \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle::class,
            \Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle::class,
            \Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineCacheBundle\DoctrineCacheBundle::class,
            \Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle::class,
        ];

        foreach ($bundles as $class) {
            yield new $class();
        }
    }

    protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollectionBuilder $routes)
    {
        $confDir = $this->getProjectDir().'/Resources/config';
        $routes->import($confDir.'/routing.yaml');
    }

    protected function configureContainer(ContainerBuilder $c, LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $confDir = $this->getProjectDir().'/Resources/config';
        $loader->load($confDir . '/{test}/*' . '.yaml', 'glob');
    }
}
```

Tests/CommandSchedulerTest.php

```
<?php

namespace Xact\CommandScheduler\Tests;

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;
use Xact\CommandScheduler\Entity\ScheduledCommand;
use Xact\CommandScheduler\Scheduler\CommandScheduler;

class CommandSchedulerTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private $entityManager;

    protected static function getKernelClass()
    {
        return TestKernel::class;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        self::bootKernel();

        $this->entityManager = static::$kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
        
        $schemaTool = new SchemaTool($this->entityManager);
        $metadata = $this->entityManager->getMetadataFactory()->getAllMetadata();
        $schemaTool->createSchema($metadata);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    protected function tearDown(): void
    {
        $this->entityManager->close();
        $this->entityManager = null;
    }

....
```